# Find a matrix such that $L(x)=\matrix A\vec x.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $L:R^2\to R^2$ is a linear transformation, $L(x)=\matrix A\vec x$.  $L\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\1\\ \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\3\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $L\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\2\\ \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1\\ \end{pmatrix}$. Find A.

It's a class exercise, I know how to solve it in a stupid way. It's easy to get the answer by solving a four by four system of equations. But my teacher solved the question in a different way, which confused me for an afternoon.
Firstly, he found the inverse of the $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&2\\ \end{pmatrix}$, it's $\begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\-1&1\\ \end{pmatrix}$. Then he wrote
$$L\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\end{pmatrix}=2\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\\end{pmatrix}+(-1)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\5\\\end{pmatrix}$$
$$L\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\\end{pmatrix}=-1\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\\end{pmatrix}+1\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-2\\\end{pmatrix}$$
So the answer is $\begin{pmatrix}4&-2\\5&-2\\\end{pmatrix}$, and I really can't understand his solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\left(\matrix{a& c\\b & d}\right)$

When we multiply the matrix A by $X_1=\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)$, we obtain

$AX_1=\left(\matrix{a\\b}\right)$

by $X_2=\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)$, we obtain

$AX_2=\left(\matrix{c\\d}\right)$

So we obtain the columns of the matrix $A$

Hence, to find the $A$, it is enough to determine the images by $L$ of each vector

$\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)$, $\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)$

It is then enough to juxtapose the two columns obtained to have $A$.

Here, we know only $A\left(\matrix{1\\1}\right)$ and $A\left(\matrix{1\\2}\right)$

The matrix $P=\left(\matrix{1&1\\1&2}\right)$ sends $\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)$ to $\left(\matrix{1\\1}\right)$ and  $\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)$ to $\left(\matrix{1\\2}\right)$

The inverse matrix $P^{-1}$ sends $\left(\matrix{1\\1}\right)$  to $\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)$ and  $\left(\matrix{1\\2}\right)$ to $\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)$

So if we want to determine x and y such that

$\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)=x\left(\matrix{1\\1}\right)+y\left(\matrix{1\\2}\right)$

we multiply by $P^{-1}$ to obtain

$P^{-1}\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)=x\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)+y\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)$

so

$\left(\matrix{2\\-1}\right)=\left(\matrix{x\\y}\right)$

Thus

$\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)=(2)\left(\matrix{1\\1}\right)+(-1)\left(\matrix{1\\2}\right)$

We repeat with $u, v$ such that

$\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)=u\left(\matrix{1\\1}\right)+v\left(\matrix{1\\2}\right)$

we multiply by $P^{-1}$ to obtain

$P^{-1}\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)=\left(\matrix{u\\v}\right)$

so

$\left(\matrix{-1\\1}\right)=\left(\matrix{u\\v}\right)$

Thus

$\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)=(-1)\left(\matrix{1\\1}\right)+(1)\left(\matrix{1\\2}\right)$

We apply $L$ using the linearity,

$L\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)=(2)L\left(\matrix{1\\1}\right)+(-1)L\left(\matrix{1\\2}\right)$

$L\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)=(-1)L\left(\matrix{1\\1}\right)+(1)L\left(\matrix{1\\2}\right)$

As $L\left(\matrix{1\\1}\right)=\left(\matrix{2\\3}\right)$ and $L\left(\matrix{1\\2}\right)=\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)$

we deduce that

$L\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)=(2)\left(\matrix{2\\3}\right)+(-1)\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)=\left(\matrix{4\\5}\right)$

$L\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)=(-1)\left(\matrix{2\\3}\right)+(1)\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right)=\left(\matrix{-2\\-2}\right)$

Hence $A=\left(\matrix{4 & -2\\5 & -2}\right)$

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand how this relates to my problem

Comment: I add some explanations, ...

Answer (score 4):

We have $$ A \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, $$
so 
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}, $$

just by multiplying both sides with 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} $$
from the right.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_1=(1,1)^T$ and $v_2=(1,2)^T$. The columns of $A$ are the images of the standard basis vectors $e_j$, so by linearity, if you know that $a_jv_1+b_jv_2=e_j$, then the $j$th column of $A$ must be $T(a_jv_1+b_jv_2)=a_jT(v_1)+b_jT(v_2)$. By the rules of matrix multiplication, those coefficients are exactly the elements of the $j$th column of $\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$: specifically, if $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\b_1&b_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},$$ then $$\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\b_1&b_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$